# Using SIGN function, but not managing to convert to negative number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following sample data:

```
Create Table #temp
(
    Value1 decimal(8,2) NULL,
    Value2 decimal(8,2) NULL,
    Value3 decimal(8,2)
)
insert into #temp
(
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
)
select
    -10,
    NULL,
    -10
union all
select
    NULL,
    5,
    5
union all
select
    -5,
    NULL,
    -0.71
union all
select
    NULL,
    5,
    8
```

What I'm needing to do is that

- When (COALESCE(Value1,Value2) and Value3 are negative, the result of Comparison needs to be a positive number.
- When (COALESCE(Value1,Value2) and Value3 are positive, the result of Comparison needs to be a negative number.

I'm looking at the SIGN function, and have the following query:

```
select 
    *,
    CASE WHEN SIGN((COALESCE(Value1,Value2) - Value3)) = -1  THEN
        ABS((COALESCE(Value1,Value2) - Value3))
    WHEN SIGN((COALESCE(Value1,Value2) - Value3)) = 1 Then
        ABS((COALESCE(Value1,Value2) - Value3)) * -1
    END 
    as Comparison

from #temp
```

What I can't work is why is row 4 is not negative (it should be -3 rather than +3)? What am I doing with the above, and is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: can you post your expected output

Comment: Sure, just edited the question.

Comment: following your explanation it should be 3 and not -3 because 5 - 8 = -3 and thus negative

Comment: Let me see if I got this correctly. You are taking the first non-null value of value1 and value2, and subtract value3 from it. Now you want the Comparison column to have the opposite sign of the subtraction result. Is that correct? because if it is, then the result in the image is correct `-05 - -0.71` equals `-4.29`, and `5 - 8` equals `-3` - and the comparison column have the exact opposite sign.

Comment: BTW, you've done a great job posting the sample data as DDL+DML. Not so great about the current result as image. It would be better to post the current (and expected) result as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question.
The way you describe the requirement fits the results you are getting - so I think perhaps your description of the requirements is wrong.
I think you might want the opposite sign when the absolute value of `value3` is smaller than the absolute value first non-null value of `value1` and `value2`, and `null` if they are equal. That would get what I think is your expected result.
Based on that assumption I came up with this query:

```
select *,
    NULLIF(ABS(COALESCE(Value1,Value2)) - ABS(Value3), 0) As [Is this what you want?],
    NULLIF((ABS(COALESCE(Value1,Value2)) - ABS(Value3)) *
    SIGN(ABS(COALESCE(Value1,Value2)) - ABS(Value3)), 0) As [A simplified version of current code]
from #temp
```

And the results:

```
Value1      Value2      Value3      Is this what you want?  A simplified version of current code
-10,00      NULL        -10,00      NULL                    NULL
NULL        5,00        5,00        NULL                    NULL
-5,00       NULL        -0,71       4,29                    4,2900
NULL        5,00        8,00        -3,00                   3,0000
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, yes the column [Is this what you want?] returns the correct value.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are making it to complicated, if I understand you correct you can do it with a simple case and isnull like this
However, according your explanation both row 3 and 4 should be positive

```
case when (isnull(value1, value2) - value3) = 0 then 
          null 
     else 
          -(isnull(value1, value2) - value3) 
end as Comparison
```

this would return

```
Value1  Value2  Value3  Comparison  
------  ------  ------  ------- 
-10,00  null    -10 ,00 null    null because -10 minus -10 = 0
null    5,00    5,00    null    null because 5 minus 5 = 0
-5,00   null    -0,71   4,29    positive because -5 minus -0.71 is negative
null    5,00    8,00    3,00    positive because 5 minus 8 is negative
```

in my result, the value for row 4 stays positive, that is because according your explanation it must be positive when value2 - value3 is negative

if I add one more test row, with values (null, 8, 5) then this will appear as -3 because 8 - 5 is positive

```
Value1  Value2  Value3  Comparison  
------  ------  ------  ------- 
-10     null    -10     null    
null    5,00    5,00    null    
-5,00   null    -0,71   4,29    
null    5,00    8,00    3,00
null    8,00    5,00    -3,00  negative because 8 minus 5 is positive
```

**EDIT**

I made my answer based on your explanation.
It seems that you want the result as in your image, not from your explanation.
If that is the case (please adjust the explanation in your question then) you can keep the logic but use abs values like this

```
case when (isnull(value1, value2) - value3) = 0 then
         null 
     else 
         (abs(isnull(value1, value2)) - abs(Value3)) 
end as Comparison
```

now it will return this

```
Value1  Value2  Value3  Comparison  
------  ------  ------  ----------  
-10,00  null    -10,00  null    
null    5,00    5,00    null    
-5,00   null    -0,71   4,29    
null    5,00    8,00    -3,00
null    8,00    5,00    3,00
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. It doesn't return +4.29 and -3.0. It returns the same as my example.

Comment: I used your data and it works with me. But like I wrote, it should return 3 in stead of -3 according your own explanation